# MVC DropDownFor second select not firing jquery change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and trying to learn it.

On my view I have a partialview with a dropdown list:

```
 <div class="panel-body col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="LocationsList">
 <div class="row row-spacing">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.locationType.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.locationType.LocationTypeID,
                        new SelectList(Model.LocationTypes,
                                       "LocationTypeID",
                                       "Name"),
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown", id = "cbLocationTypes" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.locationType.LocationTypeID, "", new { @class = "text - danger" })
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10" style="border-bottom: 2px solid darkgray;">
  <span class="caption h4 text-info">Locations</span>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="border-bottom: 2px solid darkgray;">
  <span class="caption h4 text-info">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
</div>
 @if (Model != null)
  {
    var m = Model.Locations;
    if (m.Count > 0)
    {
      foreach (var item in m)
      {
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 2px; margin-top: 2px;">
      <div class="col-sx-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 no-padding no-margin" style="width: 60px;">
        <a href="@Url.Action("SelectLocation", "Locations", new { ID = item.LocationID })" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil halfsize"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteLocation", "Locations", new { ID = item.LocationID })" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-red" ID="btnDeleteLocation" clientID="btnDeleteLocation">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove halfsize no-padding no-margin"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sx-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 no-padding no-margin" style="width: 55px;">
        @if (item.Position > 1)
        {
          <a href="@Url.Action("MoveUp", "Locations", new { ID = item.LocationID })" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-green">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up halfsize"></span>
          </a>
        }
        else
        {
          <span style="padding-left: 25px;"></span>
        }
        @if (item.Position < m.Count())
        {
          <a href="@Url.Action("MoveDown", "Locations", new { ID = item.LocationID })" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-green">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down halfsize no-padding no-margin"></span>
          </a>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
else
{
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <span class="label label-primary h4">No locations available</span>
  </div>
 }
 }
 else
{
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <span class="label label-primary h4">No locations available</span>
</div>
}
</div>
```

On the Index view where this partial is placed I have the Jquery code:

```
$('#cbLocationTypes').on('change', function () {
    var id = $('Select#cbLocationTypes').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/locations/RefreshList/' + id.toString(),
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (data) { $('#LocationsList').html(data); } })
      .done(function() {
        $('#LocationsList option[value='+id.toString()+']').prop("selected", "selected");
      })
  });
```

In my controller I have the code to run when the dropdown selection changes:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RefreshList(int id)
{
  LocationsViewModel vm = new LocationsViewModel();
  vm.Locations = db.Locations.OrderBy(m => m.Position).Where(m=>m.LocationTypeID== id).ToList();
  vm.LocationTypes = db.LocationType.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
  vm.Location = new Locations();
  vm.Location.LocationID = -1;
  vm.Location.Name = "";
  vm.Location.LocationTypeID = 1;

  return PartialView("_LocationsListPartial", vm);
}
```

The first call works perfectly.
The table on the partial is updated.

But....

When I change the selection of the dropdownlist again, nothing happens.
The jquery event is not responding (checked with break in developer panel).

What did I do wrong/ what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use delegated event as you are updating the DOM with new elements with every event execution:

```
$('#LocationsList').on('change', '#cbLocationTypes', function () {
     // code block
});
```

This syntax is:

```
$(staticParent).on(event, selector, callback);
```

Here `$(staticParent)` should be closest parent element which was available on the page at page load. Although the event can be delegated to `$(document)` too but not recommended in large size of DOM structure. This could cause slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `id = "cbLocationTypes"` from your `DropDownFor` and
try this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.locationType.LocationTypeID, new SelectList(Model.LocationTypes, "LocationTypeID", "Name"), "-- Select --", new { @class = "form-control", onchange="getlocation(this);" })


<script>
    function getlocation(element) {
    var id = $(element).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: '/locations/RefreshList/' + id.toString(),
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (data) { $('#LocationsList').html(data); } })
      .done(function() {
        $('#LocationsList option[value='+id.toString()+']').prop("selected", "selected");
      })

    }
</script>
```